# Return calling first before await

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
const isLicensesValid = async (
  licenseList: Promise<string>[]
): Promise<string> => {
  let errorText = "";
  await licenseList.forEach(async (licenseFile) => {
    await licenseFile.then(async (licenseData: string) => {
      const licenseType = await Object.keys(
        JSON.parse(licenseData).Features
      )[0];
      if (!isLicenseValid(licenseData, licenseType.toLowerCase())) {
        errorText = "One or more invalid license file in zip";
      }
    });
  });
  return errorText;
};
```

not sure why errorText always returns empty. Await is not working in then function. Can someone please suggest what is the problem here

Comment: An array's forEach method isn't promise-aware, and certainly doesn't _return_ a promise (so awaiting it is pointless).

Comment: `await Promise.all(licenseList.map(...` instead of `await licenseList.forEach`

Comment: Could you please help me with full code

Comment: But I need to traverse the list, map would return some array know.

Comment: @rajm Just read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).